# PostgreSQL, PgAdmin launching error on macOS Ventura 13.5.1

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, macos-ventura, postgresql-15

I have a MacBook Air 2020 (macOS Ventura 13.5.1). Installed PostgreSQL, worked 5-6 days without any incidents (stable). Today launched, the initial page loads and displays an error.
Previously, when it was launched, it occupied 1 port (if I'm not mistaken 5432).
Now, after the error is displayed, it occupies 1 port, but already another. (port name: Python)

```
Process:               pgAdmin 4 [93305]
Path:                  /Library/PostgreSQL/14/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/MacOS/pgAdmin 4
Identifier:            org.pgadmin.pgadmin4
Version:               7.5 (4280.88)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Translated)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-08-27 21:48:47.5482 +0600
OS Version:            macOS 13.5.1 (22G90)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        4FEA9D37-5E06-083D-88D1-DB6B8D0A0641

Sleep/Wake UUID:       5EFD95F9-F7DC-4363-A95D-7AD7F46D7297

Time Awake Since Boot: 67000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       42 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000020

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process:   exc handler [93305]

VM Region Info: 0x20 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 140722710691808
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      mapped file              7ffc8f2ec000-7ffc9e440000 [241.3M] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...t_id=894eb2a5

Kernel Triage:
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
```

Every time I open it again, the number of ports increases.
Reinstalled Postgres, installed lower version but nothing helps. Gives the same error.

Comment: PostgreSQL and pgAdmin are two different pieces of software. You can run PostgreSQL perfectly fine without pgAdmin, just use a different tool, like the default psql client. But there are hundreds of other client tools as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is due to the fact that the ports occupied by the repeated installation of yours are left unclosed as you reinstall them back and forth, you'd need to kill the process ID's that occupy the port and then continue, the error shows a segmentation fault which is likey due to a memory access violation, in this case, pgAdmin is trying to access a resource it was previously allotted, but it is already occupied by the ghost processes that were created when you uninstalled.

The best bet would be to reinstall both postgres as well as pgAdmin4 from scratch after taking the necessary backups of the postgres database, I had a similar issue as well since I have the same macbook as yours, this seemed to do the trick for me.

Comment: I removed all postgres related data (data and Library) and removed and stopped all postgres ports. Reinstalled both. At the beginning it took a long time to load, then the same error appeared